# How To pass Selected Items into a new Activity

Tags: mysql

hi I am Learning Android Spinner..in My Tutorial I have Two Spinner Country and City based on the Selection of country the City Will Be change its working but when I able to pass the selected Country and City to a new activity I got a Error Please Help Me

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: After selecting the country name and city when i click the button"UNfortunately App was Stopped @Distwo

Comment: You need to get the stack trace from logcat. That will likely tell you what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the mistake is you pass the Firstactivity layout name in secondActivy that is the reason for  app Crash

Answer (score 0):

You should use bundle to send multiple data to another activity, instead of intent.putExtra()

Ex:-

```
// In your First Activity

public void send() {


    Intent intent= new Intent(this,Display_Spinner.class);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    bundle.putString("COUNTRY", str_country);
    bundle.putString("CITY",str_city);

    intent.putExtras(bundle);

    startActivity(intent);

}

// In your second Activity

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // In your second Activity fetch data like this

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    country= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
     city=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);


    String Counrty_name=bundle.getString("COUNTRY");
    String City_name=bundle.getString("CITY");

    country.setText(Counrty_name);
    city.setText(City_name);


}

}
```

Update 3:

In your first activity's onCreate use this code

```
  country.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                str_country=country.getSelectedItem().toString();

                if (position == 0) {
                    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.city_select, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                    sp2.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
                if (position == 1) {
                    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.city_india, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                    sp2.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
                if (position == 2) {
                    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.city_pakisthan, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                    sp2.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
                if (position == 3) {
                    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.city_srilanka, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                    sp2.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

            }


            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        city.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                str_city=city.getSelectedItem().toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: i added a example, but you need to change many thing, first of all get data from spinner in OnItemSelected method..

Comment: thanks ji..the mistake is i pass the Firstactivity layout name in secondActivy that is the reason for my app Crash :) Thanks ji ur Code also works Good :)

Comment: and you also need to create OnItemClickLisener for both country and city spinner to remove confusion

Answer (score 0):

Try that in your second activity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    country= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    city=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String Counrty_name = extras.getString("Country");
        String City_name = extras.getString("City");

        country.setText(Counrty_name);
        city.setText(City_name);

    }    
}
```

Comment: thanks ji..the mistake is i pass the Firstactivity layout name in secondActivy that is the reason for my app Crash :) Thanks ji ur Code also works Good :) @Distwo

Answer (score 0):

It seems that code is correct but only one test case is missing. When user selects some country , you sets its adapter for city also make sure that you are selecting some default value for City. Since there is no selected value for city when you press button the app crashes because of toString() called on null reference at line   `String city=sp2.getSelectedItem().toString()`. Here is simple thing you should do here:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (position==0){
      adapter= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.city_select,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        sp2.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    if (position==1){
        adapter= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.city_india,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        sp2.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    if (position==2){
        adapter= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.city_pakisthan,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        sp2.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    if (position==3){
        adapter= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.city_srilanka,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        sp2.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    //write this: 
    sp2.setSelection(0);//by default first city is selected
}
```

Comment: thanks ji..the mistake is i pass the Firstactivity layout name in secondActivy that is the reason for my app Crash :) Thanks ji ur Code also works Good :)